# Big gaps, spaces between words in uiLabel text

Tags: string, text, uilabel, spaces

I have made a uiLabel with a one single word as the text/title. The label is very long and turned 90 deg. It is added to a scrollView so you can see it all eventually.

My problem is; my text is centred, so i only see the word after scrolling down for a while. I need multiple copies of the word in my .text string with nice big spaces between them, so I can see the word on screen most of the time.

Is there a nice format to 'push' words apart like this without having to type in hundreds of spaces?

e.g. @"**Label Title** /big space/ **Label Title** /big space/ **Label Title** /big space/ **Label Title**"

Answer (score 0):

I have got an idea. You can initialize the `NSString` variable used to set the title by using

```
[[NSString alloc] intiWithFormat:@"%@    %@      %@      %@", string1,string2,string3 string4];
```